# How to use data binding with fragments in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to bind the data with fragments and do it just like an activity but it shows me error. it show val cant be reassaigned and i changed val into var but still the same problem exist but Why ?

This is my fragment_login layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="login"
        type="com.binod.rojgar.viewmodel.AuthViewModel" />
</data>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ui.auth.Login">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        ...
```

This is my login class

```
    class Login : Fragment(),AuthListner {


    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentLoginBinding>(inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)
         binding.login = viewModel //this line shows error showing val cant be reassigned and i make var but still it shows same error
    viewModel.authListner=this        
    return binding.root

    }
}
```

This is my authViewModel

```
    class AuthViewModel:ViewModel(){

    var name:String?=null
    var phoneNum:String?=null
    var password:String?=null
    var comform_password:String?=null
    var authListner:AuthListner?=null

    fun loginButton(view:View)
    {
        authListner?.onStart()
        if (phoneNum.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty())
        {

            authListner?.onFailure("Invalid phone num or password")
        }

        authListner?.onSuccess()
    }

  }
```

Comment: I guess it is not the "binding" but "binding.login" which is val and cannot be reassigned. Though login variable defined in your layout is a var, normally. This error usually happens when you try to reassign a view in your layout. Is it possible that you have a view with id login, by chance?

Comment: yeah you are right . Thank a lot.

Comment: sir iam new to data binding so iam curious to know that what these code actually does ??   binding.login = viewModel 
 and  viewModel.authListner=this

Comment: Please refrain from adding quote blocks in your posts unless you are actually adding quotes (the `>` device).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Comment: yea i had tried this but the problem still exist

Comment: Yeah, i see , why you need to this `binding.login = viewModel` again ? You can delete this line.

Comment: Also check please, do you have lifecycle extensions lib ? `def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"`

Comment: i want to bind the layout so that i can use functions defined inside the view model

Comment: And use like this:  `fun loginButton() `

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way in fragment

```
    var viewDataBinding: T? = null
    private var mViewModel: V? = null
    abstract val bindingVariable: Int


   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)
        return viewDataBinding!!.root
    }


 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewDataBinding!!.setVariable(bindingVariable, mViewModel)
        viewDataBinding!!.executePendingBindings()
    }
```